# Is it possible to update a value of an object key iterated using ngFor in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

By using API response created dom elements using ngFor as follows.

HTML

```
 <div class="col-sm-2 p-1 eventDiv ripple-container" *ngFor="let actProd of actProdList;let i = index">
    <mat-card  matRipple class="p-0">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">
        <div class="w-100 ProductPrice d-flex justify-content-center">{{actProd?.PRICE}}<span class="pl-1" [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></div>

        <button type="button" (click)="decrement(actProd?.CODE,i)" class="btnStyles">–</button>
        <input type="text" #TotalCartCount readonly class="quantityBox" value="{{mItemCount}}">
        <button type="button" (click)="increment(actProd?.CODE,i)" class="btnStyles">+</button>
        </div>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Typescript

```
increment(ItemId:number,index:number) {
    this.mItemCount += 1;
  }
```

What I want to do is, when the user clicks on the "+" button I need to update the price. How to achieve this without refreshing the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it might serve you better to create two new properties. One for the product quantity and one for total price that changes according to the quantity. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  mItemCount = 1;
  actProdList = [
    { 'CODE': 1, 'PRICE': 25 },
    { 'CODE': 2, 'PRICE': 99 },
    { 'CODE': 3, 'PRICE': 100 },
    { 'CODE': 4, 'PRICE': 300 },
    { 'CODE': 5, 'PRICE': 12 }
  ];
  mCurrencyCode = '&#36;';

  constructor() {
    this.actProdList.forEach(product => {     // <- create new properties here
      product['quantity'] = 0;
      product['totalPrice'] = 0;
    });
  }

  increment(ItemId: number, index: number) {
    this.actProdList[index]['quantity'] += 1;
    this.actProdList[index]['totalPrice'] = this.actProdList[index]['PRICE'] * this.actProdList[index]['quantity'];
  }

  decrement(ItemId: number, index: number) {
    this.actProdList[index]['quantity'] -= 1;
    this.actProdList[index]['totalPrice'] = this.actProdList[index]['PRICE'] * this.actProdList[index]['quantity'];
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="col-sm-2 p-1 eventDiv ripple-container" *ngFor="let actProd of actProdList;let i = index">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2">
    <div class="w-100 ProductPrice d-flex justify-content-center">{{actProd?.totalPrice}} <span class="pl-1" [innerHtml]="mCurrencyCode"></span></div>

    <button type="button" (click)="decrement(actProd?.CODE,i)" class="btnStyles">–</button>
    <input type="text" #TotalCartCount readonly class="quantityBox" value="{{actProd?.quantity}}">
    <button type="button" (click)="increment(actProd?.CODE,i)" class="btnStyles">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zv3etl)